# Finding codex pages in Assasin's Creed 2

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I'm at 28/30 codex pages and can't access my next memory sequence without all 30. I've been given a map to the locations of all the pages, though, and with that I've roamed around all 4 cities, but couldn't find any more. Any tips on how to get past this?

Comment: A few of the last codex pages crop up only in the storyline memories - have you completely all the standard memories (ie, excluding the side-quests)?

Comment: If you could say exactly which two you're missing, it would help as well.

Comment: Ah whoops, it looks like I've found them. I've heard some discussion on the internet about how there was a bug in the game and I'd have to start over. Looks like that's not the case, the pages were lurking behind the clutter on the map.

Comment: @Tejaswi Perhaps you'd like to answer your own question then, maybe with a screenshot!

Comment: @Tejaswi - That's also why it lets you turn on/off the map markers selectively!